# Why Dispose is being called on DataContract even though the service still refers to it?

Tags: c#, wcf, idisposable, datacontract

I have defined the following `DataContract` which implements `IDisposable`:

```
[DataContract]
public class RegularFileMetadata : FileMetadataBase, IDisposable
{
   bool _Disposed = false; //note this!

   //...

   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
      if (!_Disposed)
      {
          //...
          _Disposed = true; //note this too!
      }
   }
   public void Dispose()
   {
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }
}
```

And I call the following service method passing an instance of the above data contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(RegularFileMetadata))]
Guid BeginUpload(FileMetadataBase metadata);
```

In the implementation of `BeginUpload`, I simply save *metadata* in a dictionary as:

```
Dictionary<Guid, RegularFileMetadata> _Dict;

public Guid BeginUpload(FileMetadataBase fileMetadata)
{
    //...
    var metadata = fileMetadata as RegularFileMetadata; 
    Guid sessionId = Guid.NewGuid();
    _Dict.Add(sessionId, metadata); //metadata SAVED!
    return sessionId ;
}
```

My question is, immediately after returning from this method, why `Dispose()` is called even though I've saved the instance in the dictionary `_Dict`?

I have verified that `Dispose()` method is called on the *same* instance which I have saved in my dictionary, as `_Disposed` becomes `true` for the *saved* object, i.e `_Dict[sessionId]._Disposed` becomes `true`!

The service behavior of my service is set as:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Comment: Are you ssure that Dispose(..) is called on the **same** instance you created ? I mean, *may be* there was created another instance of the class and Dispose(..) was called on *that* one. Check *hashcode* of the instance you get Dispose(..) on...

Comment: @Tigran: I updated my question with : *"I have verified that Dispose() method is called on the same instance which I have saved in my dictionary, as the _Disposed becomes true for the saved object."*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's being disposed because that object "belongs" to WCF - it created the object instance out of thin air, to pass as a parameter to your method. And, it's kind enough to observe that this object implements `IDisposable`, so it's disposing of it once your method completes.

<strike>If you want an instance of this object to hang onto after your method completes, then you need to create such an instance yourself, copying relevant details from one instance to the other.</strike>

> why `Dispose()` is called even though I've saved the instance in the dictionary `_Dict`

Because the `Dispose` pattern has *nothing* to do with references and garbage collection. All that matters is that, whenever references to a disposable object are being passed around between multiple methods/actors/agents, that there is an agreement on "who" is responsible for calling `Dispose` and when. In this instance, the "who" is the WCF infrastructure.

---

Correction - you can alter this behaviour by adding the [`OperationBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute) attribute to your method, and setting [`AutoDisposeParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute.autodisposeparameters) to false:

```
[OperationBehavior(AutoDisposeParameters=false)]
public Guid BeginUpload(FileMetadataBase fileMetadata)
{
    //...
    var metadata =
```